# Get a user's avatar VK SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, vk

Good day. The question on the use of library VK. How to get a profile picture, using VKSDK\
Can not find the right information on the Internet.

Answer (score 7):

In your request you need to specify one of the following fields: 
photo_50 or photo_100 or photo_200:

```
VKRequest yourRequest = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,"photo_50"))
```

After that when you will retrieve users data you can get photo_50:

```
yourRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
    super.onComplete(response);

    VKUsersArray usersArray = (VKUsersArray) response.parsedModel;

    for (VKApiUserFull userFull : usersArray) {
          Log.i(TAG, "Avatar image URL: " + userFull.photo_50);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But instead of get(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_50") you should use VKRequest yourRequest = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_50"));

Answer (score 1):

**For android apps:**

You get the profile photo by sending a request like this:

```
    https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=5337911&v=5.23&fields=photo_50
```

**For iframe applications:**

You should use [`users.get`](https://vk.com/dev/users.get) method of `VK.api`

```
    VK.api('users.get', {
        user_ids: id,
        fields: "photo_50"
    }, function(data) {
        photo_50 = data.response[0].photo_50;
    });
```

If you don't know what is `VK.api` then you should read about [Javascript SDK](https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK)

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend I fix this problem with my own solution like this: And this works for 100%

```
public class RootVKAccount
{
    public List<VKAccount> response { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject("response")]
public class VKAccount
{
    [JsonProperty("photo_200")]
    public string UserImgUrl { get; set; }
}

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create($@"https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?owner_id={UserId}&fields=photo_200&access_token={Token}&v=5.92") as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse respons = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

Stream jsonStream = respons.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonStream);
string jsonStr = r.ReadToEnd();
r.Dispose();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootVKAccount>(jsonStr);

string uri = obj.response[0].UserImgUrl;
new WebClient().DownloadFile(uri, avatarFullPAth);
```